# Add a randomly generated number to a latex document to discourage cheating on an exam

Tags: compiling, exam, random-numbers

I am trying to cut down on a particular kind of cheating during my in-class exams. What some students are doing is taking pictures of the exam (while I am looking somewhere else), and uploading them to Chegg. Then, looking back later at the solutions posted by "tutors". I've cut down on this in a variety of ways, but it still occurs.

I use LaTeX to generate the exams. I would like to embed a unique number into every LaTeX document so that if someone takes a picture of it, I will be able to associate that number with a particular person (by looking at their exam when the turn it in).

The way I envision this is a simple tag in the LaTeX code, like

```
\randomnumber{seed}
```

which I can compile with

```
latex doc.tex -option=seed
```

I would then write a script to do this for like 100 exams, just a loop

```
for i=0,n
latex doc-i.tex option=seed+i
```

(or something).

Anyone have a method for doing this? Or a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I've deleted my earlier comments. I have no idea how to help you using what you call "vanilla latex".

Comment: I used to combine C++ programs and LaTeX to generate random worksheets so that each one had completely different problems.  You could do it with pgfmath, but C++ does math better.  See http://www.elfsoft2000.com/worksheets/index.htm for examples.  BTW, the "batch number" was the random seed, in case I needed to reproduce it.

Answer (score 6):

All tex engines have a inbuilt random number generator. You can simply use it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}
\fpeval{randint(10000,99999)}

\end{document}
```

First compilation:
[image]

Next compilation
[image]

The seed is normally derived from the system time, but you can also set it if you want.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: Can't really upload a screenshot right now, but it is a watermark using tikz in 3 places in each question according to its (question's) height and the ID width.

You could have a latex code for your questions like:

```
\xdef\DocID{12345678901234567890}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\newsavebox\QuestionBox
\newsavebox\IDBox
\savebox{\IDBox}{\hbox{\DocID}}
\newlength\QuestionHeight
\newlength\QuestionWidth
\newlength\IDWidth
\newcounter{QuestionCounter}
\newcommand{\Question}[2]{\stepcounter{QuestionCounter}
\def\QNum{\the\value{QuestionCounter}}
\savebox{\QuestionBox}{\vbox{\noindent{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]\coordinate(A\QNum);\end{tikzpicture}\bfseries #1} #2\hfill\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]\coordinate (B\QNum);\end{tikzpicture}}}
\setlength{\QuestionHeight}{\ht\QuestionBox}
\setlength{\QuestionWidth}{\wd\QuestionBox}
\setlength{\IDWidth}{\wd\IDBox}
\usebox{\QuestionBox}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\pgfmathsetmacro\angleATan{atan(\QuestionHeight/\IDWidth)}
\node[opacity=0.4] at ($(A\QNum)!0.5!(B\QNum) - ({0.3*\QuestionWidth},0)$) {\rotatebox{\angleATan}{\usebox{\IDBox}}};
\node[opacity=0.4] at ($(A\QNum)!0.5!(B\QNum)$) {\rotatebox{\angleATan}{\usebox{\IDBox}}};
\node[opacity=0.4] at ($(A\QNum)!0.5!(B\QNum)+({0.3*\QuestionWidth},0)$) {\rotatebox{\angleATan}{\usebox{\IDBox}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\Question{Question 1}{Here is a first short question}

\Question{Question 2}{Here is a longer question that will last at least two lines with an equation \[F(x)=3\cdot x\] to be solved for \(F(x)=0\)}

\end{document}
```

Then could create a document for each ID (using a simple C -or whatever code- that replaces first line for each student -ask me for it if you think you need help on this- and then if (s)he upload somewhere the photo with her/him ID ... you could find easily... But if -like many of them- have a tutor and send him private -via email or whatever- you can't of course find him/her)

Comment: Ohhhhh a watermark, that sounds like an amazing idea. The game here is to know who posts something on Chegg after they turn in their exams, but since I have their exams I can match the watermark to their names.

Comment: @levitopher ... If you need a simple c script about this, you could share a way (a sample of your question bank) that you use your questions in the exams in order to provide such a script too (a c code or something)